# Show form field and focus

Tags: jquery

In have a selector and when I select a particular option it shows additional form field. At that point I want to switch the focus to the new field. Here's what I tried but it does not seem to work. What am I missing?:

```
   $('#mySelector').change(function () {
        var st = $(this).val();
        if (st == 'a') {                
            $('#a').show(function(){
                $('#aField').focus();
            });
            $('#b').hide();
        } else if (st == 'b') {
            $('#a').hide();
            $('#b').show(function(){
                $('#bField').focus();
            });             
        } else {
            $('#a, #b').hide();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Can you post your HTML too in a JSFiddle?

Comment: What part doesn't work? The show/hide or only the focus?

Answer (score 0):

This works. Your error lies elsewhere in your code. Likely a typo in your HTML:

```
<select id="mySelector">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="a">a</option>
    <option value="b">b</option>
</select>

<div id="a">
    <input type="text" value="A field" id="aField" />
</div>

<div id="b">
    <input type="text" value="B field" id="bField" />
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zwR4F/